# Creating Video Element in Next Js with TypeScript dynamically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

How do I create the video element in Next JS with TypeScript dynamically ? Creating the video element by using React.createElement('video') just has a type of HTMLElement, what I actually want is of the type HTMLVideoElement.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Z2w.png)

Comment: you can use document.createElement()

Comment: I'm using next js...

Comment: If you want you can forcefully cast the variable like this: `const video = React.createElement('video') as unknown as HTMLVideoElement` but I'm not sure if the return object from `React.createElement('video')`  matches HTMLVideoElement interface

Comment: [`createElement`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createElement) creates a React element, not a DOM element. You want [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75262771/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

When the code renders it didn't get the html elements so here the html element will be create/append after the html renders properly

```
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      const video = videoRef.current;

      call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
      });

      call.on("close", () => {
        video.remove();
      });
    }
  }, [call, videoRef]);

  return <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay playsInline />;
```

I believe this will meet your requirements.